# Query two tables (get max from 2 columns on 2nd table)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have two tables,

First: Cars
ID(primary),Name

Second : Sold
ID(primary),CarID,Price,SoldUnits

How i can query to get car name where (Price * SoldUnits) is maximum?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To find the top selling car:

```
select  top 1 c.name
from    cars c
join    sold s
on      s.CarID = c.ID
group by
        c.Name
order by
        sum(Price * SoldUnits) desc
```

To find the car with the single biggest sale:

```
select  top 1 c.name
from    cars c
join    sold s
on      s.CarID = c.ID
order by
        Price * SoldUnits desc
```

Comment: so easy for someone with sql expirience :). Thanks, perfect!